# MVC2 Html.TextBox changes size slightly when validation fails

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I am using MVC2 and .NET 3.5. Weirdly when a textbox validation fails the texbox height is reduced by 2 pixels. Has anyone seen this before or know of a fix?

Thanx,

Answer (score 0):

Its probably the size of the surrounding border used when an error is displayed. Check the style sheet for both the normal and error condition textboxes and ensure that the border widths match.